# Executable jar and double-click

Tags: java, maven, jar, swt

I'm in the process of creating a fairly extensive desktop application using SWT. To generate an executable jar file I use maven-shade-plugin in version 2.1. After generating a file, typical double-clicking does not work (the system tries to open a few seconds and stops). Calling from the console

> java -jar pakiet.jar

works very well.

Previously, I created a project with SWING with using the same plugin and double click worked without a problem. Is the problem may be to use SWT?

Java version 1.7.0_25
OS Windows 7 Professional x64

Comment: which operating system ?

Comment: Have you tried the console to see if it works?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a *.bat file with the following content:

start javaw -jar pakiet.jar

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) my my SWT applications, works really well. You can even bundle the jre to avoid any dependencies on the target machine. Supports a splash screen, icon for the exe, you can enforce single instance of the exe, min/max jre versions, graceful error message if jre not supplied etc etc.